# How to click somewhere out of the screen?

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, mouse-click

I am using Windows 7 64Bit. I installed After Effects CS6. And I am now trying to install Motion Boutique Newton 2. I have 1024*768 resolution (and thats the maximum for my pc. I know thats odd) and thus, the Newton 2 license accept windows is cutoff so I can't click the accept button in anyway. This is really frustrating. The license Window can't be re-sized or moved.

Hitting the Tab key to get focus of the accept button does not work. Re-sizing the Windows does not work. Manually registering the dll files of the plugin does not work. Attached are the screenshots.

How do I accept it? Can I move my mouse out of the Window?

[image: Full Screen Pic]
[image: After Re-sizing Windows Pic]

Comment: in first screnshot, hiting tab should work

Answer (score 0):

Accept button will only be enabled if `Accept the terms` radio button is **selected** .. As I can see from the screenshot,  `I donot Accept the terms` radio button is selected.

Select the first radio button, and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get focus on *Accept* button.

Comment: Tried it... Doesn't work.